# While storing server response in userdefaults....I am getting error

Tags: swift3

While storing server response in userdefaults....I am getting error........

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue
>   encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x600002fe7720'

This is My code

```
if let responseObject = response.array  {

   print(responseObject)

  let bookingDetails = responseObject[0].dictionary!

  let myData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:bookingDetails)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(myData, forKey: "userJson")

}
```

Comment: What is `bookingDetails` exactly?

Comment: [String : JSON]

Answer (score 0):

To be able to archive custom classes the **class** must adopt `NSCoding`. That's what the error message tells you.

JSON (in `SwiftyJSON`) is a struct, it cannot be archived with `NSKeyedArchiver` at all.

Drop `SwiftyJSON` and `NSCoding`, use `Codable` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Please encode the response and store it in userDefaults and when you want to use these value the fetch it and decode.

It may helps you.

Comment: if let responseObject = response.array  {
                    
                    print(responseObject)
                    
                    let bookingDetails = responseObject[0].dictionary!
                    let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(bookingDetails)
                     UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "details")